# Request runtime permissions for widget

Tags: android, android-widget, android-permissions

Default permission always disabled. I need to ask for it in runtime. How to request runtime permission in `AppWidgetProvider`?

**It doesn't work:**

```
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR);
    if (permissionCheck != 0) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR},
                    1);
        }
    }
```

**Gives error:**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
```

Comment: You need to use activity `context`

Comment: @AskNilesh widgets don't have activity, that's the point of them.